# If a random variable is bounded, does it mean its expectation is bounded?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, stochastic-processes, random-variables

Suppose I have random variables $(X_n)_n$ that have a lower bound 
$$X_n > a \qquad \forall n$$
and that are finite (which I think this means that they also have an upper bound, and so $|X_n|< b$ for some $b>0$, but I am not sure about the definition of finite random variables, cause I can't find it anywhere).

Does it mean that $X_n$ are bounded in $\mathcal{L}^1$? In other words, does it mean that

$$\sup_n \mathbb{E}[|X_n|] <\infty$$

What about $\sup_n\mathbb{E}[|X_n|^p]<\infty$ for $p>1$?

Basically my question is: knowing that the random variables are bounded, do we know if their expectation is bounded?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $|X_n| \leq M$ then  $E|X_n| \leq M$ too. If $a \leq X_n \leq b$ for all $n$ then  $E|X_n| \leq |a|+|b|$ for  all $n$.  Also, $E|X_n|^{p} \leq (|a|+|b|)^{p}$.

However saying that $X_n$ is finite does not mean that $X_n$'s are bounded. If the only hypothesis is $X_n >a$ it does no follow that $EX_n$ is bounded: take $X_n=n+a$ for a counter-example.

Comment: The book is not clear. But for sure I know there are two assumptions: one is $X_n > a$ and the other one is that $X_n$ are finite random variable, however nowhere in the book it defines what it means for them to be finite. So I assumed it meant that their magnitude is bounded?

Comment: Essentially, often in the book people do the following: They prove that a supermartingale $(X_n)_n$ is bounded from below, and then they say "and therefore by Doob's convergence theorem it means that it converges to some random variable". However, the assumption for Doob's convergence theorem is that $\mathbb{E}[|X_n|]<\infty$

Comment: Basically Doob's convergence theorem says: _Let $X$ be a supermartingale, which is bounded in $\mathcal{L}^1$. Then, there exists a random variable $X_{\infty} \in\mathcal{L}^1(\Omega, \mathcal{F}_{\infty}, \mathbb{P})$ such that $X_n\to X_{\infty}$ almost surely_

Comment: And often people prove that the martingale is finite and that it is bounded below, and then they conclude that they can use Doob's theorem. Hence my question

Comment: If $(Y_n)$ is a non-negative supermartingale then $EY_n$ is decreasing and non-negative. Hence $\sup E|Y_n| =\sup EY_n <\infty$. If $X_n$ is a supermartingale such that $X_n >a$ the take $Y_n=x_n-a$ to show that $\sup E|Y_n| <\infty$.

Comment: Very clear! The only thing I don't understand is in the very first line. How do you know that if $(Y_n)$ is a non-negative supermartingale, then $\mathbb{E}[Y_n]$ will be decreasing and non-negative? Is it because of $\mathbb{E}[Y_{n+1}\mid \mathcal{F}_n] \leq Y_n$ ? I'm super new to martingales and I still struggle to understand these things. If that's the case, then can we consider $\mathbb{E}[Y_n\mid \mathcal{F}_{n-1}]$ the same as the $\mathbb{E}[Y_n]$ you are referring to?