# Uniform integrability of a martingale

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, martingales, uniform-integrability

Let $\left(X_{n}\right)_{n \geq 0}$ is a martingale with $X_{0}=0$. Assume

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} E\left(\left(X_{n}-X_{n-1}\right)^{2}\right)<\infty .$$

Show that the martingale is uniformly integrable.

---

I have a result that says that a martingale $X=(X)_{n\geq 0}$ is bounded ($\sup_nE(X_n^2)<\infty$) if and only if

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} E\left(\left(X_{n}-X_{n-1}\right)^{2}\right)<\infty $$

However, this says nothing about the fact that if the martingale is uniformly integrable.

I have a theorem saying that if $\sup_{X\in \mathcal{H}}E(|X|^p)<\infty$ for some $p>1$, then the class of random variables $\mathcal{H}$ is uniformly integrable. Is this applicable here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is directly applicable!

Let us restate this useful criterion:

Basically boundedness in $L^p$ for $p>1$ (note that $p=1$ does not work) implies that a family of random variables $(X_i)_{i \in \mathbb N}$ is uniformly integratable, more precisely:

**Lemma**: Let $(X_i)_{i \in \mathbb N}$ be a family of random variables such that
$$
\sup_{i \in \mathbb N} \mathbb E[|X_i|^p] \leq C < \infty,
$$
then $(X_i)_{i \in \mathbb N}$ is u.i.

**Proof:** Let $p>1$ and $\sup_{i \in \mathbb N} \mathbb E[|X_i|^p] \leq C$. Then observe that
$$
\mathbb E[|X_i| \mathbb 1_{|X_i| > K}] \leq \mathbb E\bigg[\frac{|X_i|^{p-1}}{K^{p-1}} |X_i| \mathbb 1_{|X_i|>K}\bigg] \leq \frac{1}{K^{p-1}} \mathbb E[|X_i|^p] \leq \frac{C}{K^{p-1}}.
$$
Now taking the supremum over $i \in \mathbb N$ and $K \to \infty$ shows that $\{X_i\}_{i \in \mathbb N}$ is u.i.

So you are indeed already done:

Since you already know that your condition implies that $\sup_{i \in \mathbb N} \mathbb E[|X_i|^2] \leq C < \infty$ we know that $\{X_i\}$ is bounded in $L^2$ and by above this is sufficies.

**Appendix on Boundedness:** Let us first speak some basic observations:

1. If $|X_n| \leq M$ then $\mathbb E[|X_n|] \leq M$.
2. If $M_1 \leq X_n \leq M_2$ then $\mathbb E[|X_n|] \leq |M_1| + |M_2|$ (rewrite the integral in terms o positive and negative part of $X_n$
3. If $M_1 \leq X_n \leq M_2$ then $\mathbb E[|X_n|] \leq (|M_1| + |M_2|)^p$

For more I advise to check out the following question [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3433896/if-a-random-variable-is-bounded-does-it-mean-its-expectation-is-bounded].

Generally speaking one also knows that if $X$ is bounded in $L^q$ for $1 \leq p \leq q$ then it is also bounded in $L^p$ by applying Hölder's inequality. Usually the idea about this can maybe explained in terms of bounded second moments, i.e. that $E[|X|^2] < \infty$, since then not only the the absolute value $|X|$ is finite almost surely but also it's second moment $E[|X|^2]$, which in case that $X \sim N(0,\sigma)$ gives you automatically that also the variance of single random variable or the variance of a whole family of r.v. has finite variance. Does this help or do you have a more specific question about this?

Comment: This makes sense however I am a bit lost on the boundedness. It is indeed bounded by my first argument but does the second argument imply that it is bounded in $L^2$?

Comment: boundedness in general is really not intuitive for me at all.

Comment: I am a bit confused, I believe in your text above you state already that you know that the given condition gives you $L^2$ boundedness. This is all you need for the exercise by above. I guess you are confused regarding why there are two notions of „boundedness“, i.e L^p boundedness and a random variable is bounded, shall I give some details on this?

Comment: yes exactly that is what I am confused on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I accepted it but a explanation on the above comment is much appreciated

Comment: It is edited, I hope it is now a bit more clear, however the question is a bit vague, but I tried to shed some light on multiple aspects. Do you have a remaining question you can open a new question, and pin it here :)

Comment: I am trying to solve multiple problems which is why I wanted some more information on the issue at hand. I have some fundamental missunderstandings of how the convergence works and how boundness works. My other thread is this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4673297/show-that-x-is-finite-and-ex-infty

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's applicable. You have $\sup_n E(|X_n|^2)<\infty,$ and $2>1.$

Perhaps the confusion is the "class" thing? Here the class in question is $\{X_n: n\in \mathbb N\}.$

Answer (score 0):

Let **A** denote your condition
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} E\left[ (X_{n} - X_{n-1})^{2} \right] < \infty, $$ **B**(p) denote the condition
$$ \sup_{n} E\left( |X_{n}|^{p} \right) < \infty,$$
and **C** denote uniform integrability.

The results you have so far are:
[**A** $\iff$ **B**(2)], and [**B**(p) $\implies$ **C**] for all $p > 1$.
From the first result, we can get that [**A** $\implies$ **B**(2)] by ignoring the other direction. From the second result, we can get [**B**(2) $\implies$ **C**] by considering $p = 2$. Composing the implication, we get [**A** $\implies$ **C**].